# How to get the appendix pdf to start at the same page?

Tags: pdfpages, books, appendix

[image]I am struggling to get the pdf in the appendix to start on the same page as the appendix chapter begins. In addition, the headline is not included with the pdf. Which means that I get a headline, followed by the blank page, and then the attachment on the next page.

I got:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\chapter{Appendix}
  \label{chap:Appendix}

\appendix

\section{NSD approval}
  %\begin{appendix}
\centering
\includepdf[pages=-]{Meldeskjema.pdf}
  %\end{appendix}
```

Does someone know how to solve this? I have tried a set of options found here on stack, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. This also serves as a test case ensuring that the solution actually works for you - sometimes the solution depends on the documentclass and packages.

Comment: I think what you need is to make use of the `pagecommand` option to `\includepdf`. But, since you are including a full page pdf, may need to `scale` as well.

Comment: Sorry! First time posting here :D My dc is: \documentclass[12pt]{book}

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But, it is better if you edit the question to include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that has the appropriate packages as well.

Comment: Is `Meldeskjema.pdf` a single-page PDF?

Comment: Is this PDF a single page? In that case, simply using `\includegraphics{Meldeskjema.pdf}` might work. ETA: What @Werner said (or was about to, I suppose.)

Comment: No, its a two-page pdf... thats kind of where my issue is, because i cant seem to include all pages using different methods.

Comment: You could overlay the first page using either tikz or \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the content of the included pdf to start on the same page as where the Appendix title is, then the page will need to be shrunk and shifted over to allow for the Appendix/section headings. Also, making use of `pagecommand=` option allows for the chapter/section heading to be on the same page.

[image]

#### Notes:

- I applied the `frame` option to `\includepdf` to see the location of the pages from the included pdf. You may want to remove that in your actual usage, unless you desire to hightlight that it is an included pdf.

---

If you have any control over the pdf you are inserting, you can ensure that the content on the first page starts past where the chapter/section heading needs to be and then you can get away without any scaling, or apply the same scale to each inserted page.

[image]

#### Code: `No Control Over Inserted PDF Content`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[
    pages=1,
    scale=0.7,% initial page needs to be shrunk sufficiently to fit
    frame,
    offset={2.5cm, -1.0cm},% shift the page over to allow for chapter/section heading.
    pagecommand={%
        \chapter{Appendix}
        \label{chap:Appendix}
        \appendix
        \section{NSD approval}
    }
]{test.pdf}
\includepdf[
    pages=2-,
    scale=0.9,% other pages can use a larger scale
    frame,
    %offset={2.5cm, -1.0cm},
]{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

#### Code: `Adjust Inserted PDF Content`

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.tex}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \begin{document}
    \vspace*{7.5cm}% <-- leave room on first page for what ever chapter/appendix this is inserted in
    \lipsum[1-12]
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[
    pages=1,
    pagecommand={%
        \chapter{Appendix}
        \label{chap:Appendix}
        \appendix
        \section{NSD approval}
    }
]{test.pdf}
\includepdf[
    pages=2-,
]{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to overlay the first page using TikZ and `\includegrpahics`.  I placed the page below the upper left corner in case the even/odd pages were asymmetrical.  Test5.pdf was just some two page document.

If you want appendices at the end of a chapter, you should use the appendix package.  Normally book class makes each chapter an appendix (A,B, ...).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Appendix}
  \label{chap:Appendix}

\begin{appendices}

\section{NSD approval}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[below right, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west)
  {\includegraphics[page=1, width=\paperwidth]{test5.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage

\includepdf[pages=2-]{test5.pdf}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```